# Is there a way to maintain ASP.NET ViewState in dynamically rendered HTML control?

Tags: asp.net, html, render

I want to make custom control which has couple of `<input type='checkbox' />` controls which I render in Render method.
Is it possible to retain ViewState (e.g. checked or not) on these Controls?

There is a way of doing this by using ASP.NET server CheckBox control, 
adding them in OnLoad event with this.Controls.Add(),
and giving them same Ids everytime, 
but I don't wat to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want ViewState restored to a dynamic control, you must re-create that control *before* the load event.  That means putting that code in the `Init` handler.

Comment: How should I recreate an HTML control before Load event?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a control, make sure you add them to the page *first*, and set any properties on them afterwards. This because, in order for the ViewState manager to consider the control for management, it has to detect a change, and it can only detect changes after the control has been added to the Controls collection.

It is also important to **set an explicit ID**. When ViewState is saved and restored, the control IDs must match.

Also make sure that you create the controls in the right moment (OnInit) of the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the ViewState directly:

```
bool checked = (bool)(ViewState["ThisControlCheckState"] ?? false);
if (checked) {
    write("<input ... >");
}
else {
    write("<input ... >");
}
```

To save the value form the user, you could do something like this in the PostBack:

```
ViewState["ThisControlCheckState"] = request.Params["checkboxName"].ToString() == "1";
```